# Changes to Javascript created element doesn't reflect to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a class, that is supposed to display grey overlay over page and display text and loading gif. Code looks like this:

```
function LoadingIcon(imgSrc) {
    var elem_loader = document.createElement('div'),
        elem_messageSpan = document.createElement('span'),
        loaderVisible = false;

    elem_loader.style.position = 'absolute';
    elem_loader.style.left = '0';
    elem_loader.style.top = '0';
    elem_loader.style.width = '100%';
    elem_loader.style.height = '100%';
    elem_loader.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    elem_loader.style.textAlign = 'center';

    elem_loader.appendChild(elem_messageSpan);
    elem_loader.innerHTML += '<br><img src="' + imgSrc + '">';

    elem_messageSpan.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';

    this.start = function () {
        document.body.appendChild(elem_loader);
        loaderVisible = true;
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        if (loaderVisible) {
            document.body.removeChild(elem_loader);
            loaderVisible = false;
        }
    };

    this.setText = function(text) {
        elem_messageSpan.innerHTML = text;
    };

    this.getElems = function() {
        return [elem_loader, elem_messageSpan];
    };
}
```

Problem is, when I use setText method, it sets innerHTML of elem_messageSpan, but it doesn't reflect to the span, that was appended to elem_loader. You can use getElems method to find out what both elements contains.

Where is the problem? Because I don't see single reason why this shouldn't work.

---

EDIT:
I call it like this:

```
var xml = new CwgParser('cwg.geog.cz/cwg.xml'),
    loader = new LoadingIcon('./ajax-loader.gif');
xml.ondataparse = function() {
    loader.stop();
    document.getElementById('cover').style.display = 'block';
};
loader.setText('Loading CWG list...');
loader.start();
xml.loadXML();
```

xml.loadXML() is function that usually takes 3 - 8 seconds to execute (based on download speed of client), thats why I'm displaying loading icon.

Comment: are you sure that is does not appended to span ? you can see doc tree  with inspect element in developer tools in all browser

Comment: How are you calling `LoadingIcon()` and then calling `setText()`.  We need to see that code.